# Monitor tempdb iops on Azure VM

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, azure-vm

I've inherited SQL on Azure VMs where not all the tempdb files are on the ephemeral D: drive. I'd like to move them back there as that is the MS recommended location for latency reasons. However, before doing so I want to see the current IOPS and throughput to make sure the move won't max out on either of them.
Has anyone been able to view the metrics of the ephemeral drive e.g. IOPS consumed percentage? I can see metrics for other disks (the OS disk and all the data disks) but not that D: drive.
Any ideas please?